# Bug: findMeetingTimes throws “AttendeesUnavailable” even for optional attendees

Tags: outlook, office365, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I'm trying to use the `https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/findmeetingtimes` endpoint documented on the [MSDN Outlook Calendar website](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/user_findmeetingtimes).  When I call the endpoint with the following payload:

```
 {  
  "Attendees": [  
    {  
      "Type": "optional",   
      "EmailAddress": {  
        "Name": "Studio 3", 
        "Address": "PDXICSTUDIO3@rogueInc.onmicrosoft.com"  
      }  
    }  
  ],   

  "TimeConstraint": {  
    "ActivityDomain":"Unrestricted", 
    "Timeslots": [  
      {  
        "Start": {  
          "DateTime": "2018-10-30T19:30:00",   
          "TimeZone": "UTC"  
        },   
        "End": {  
          "DateTime": "2018-10-30T20:30:00",   
          "TimeZone": "UTC"  
        }  
      }  
    ] 
  },   
  "ReturnSuggestionReasons": "true", 
  "IsOrganizerOptional": false, 
  "MaxCandidates": 99 
  }
```

I get an empty meeting time suggestions response with the reason provided as "AttendeesUnavailable".  It doesn't seem to matter whether I declare the type of the attendee as "optional", "required", or "resource" as specified in the [attendeeBase Resource Type documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/attendeebase).  This seems like a bug with the GraphAPI and I'm unsure as to how to proceed.

Comment: Do you tried https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/findmeetingtimes? You post are not the same as the docs.

Comment: This is the v2.0 version of the call, not v1.0.

Comment: Graph only have beta and v1.0.

Comment: The endpoint (https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/findmeetingtimes ) also works, and accepts the same payloads as graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/findmeetingtimes.  We can't use graph because our ADAL app registration permissions are not configured for it.

Comment: Even if they accept the same request body. But they are not exactly the same.

Comment: Can you explain the differences, or point me towards documentation that explains them?